# Сопоставить два датафрейма оставив строки которые есть в обоих

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy

Есть два датафрейма. Не очень понимаю каким образом их можно сопоставить. В первом есть столбец Time, в нем значения, но во втором файле не все значения Time есть. Соотвественно как правильно их сопоставить, чтобы получился df1, в котором есть только те строки, которые есть в df2. Иногда во втором также может не быть значения с Date которая есть в df1.
Пример
df1

```
Date    Time    Price
20190603    102000  61.14
20190603    102100  61.13
20190603    102200  61.16
20190603    102300  61.15
20190603    102400  61.08
```

df2

```
Date    Time    Price
20190603    102000  53.01
20190603    102200  53.02
20190603    102300  53
20190603    102400  52.98
20190603    103200  52.97
```

Ну и результат df1

```
Date    Time    Price
20190603    102000  61.14
20190603    102200  61.13
20190603    102300  61.16
20190603    102400  61.15
20190603    103200  61.08
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что-то вроде такого, аналогично JOIN в SQL:

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='inner', on=['Date','Time'])
```

Нужные столбцы потом только надо будет отобрать.